# Parallel For Loop Selenium C# - NOT A TEST

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

I wanna make a parallel For loop that will open an some changed link.
But I get an exception when I'm doing it in parallel..

Any Help?

I searched for solutions online and only found ones that are using Nunit (Runming few selected test - Not my case).

Ex.

```
Parallel.For(0, 5, i => {
#region Driver Init
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Galdo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
options.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 1");
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
#endregion       chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/id="+i);
            });
```

Exception :

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException HResult=0x80131500 Message=unknown
>   error: failed to write prefs file (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.42.591088
>   (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64) Source=WebDriver StackTrace: at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String –

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method like this one:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--user-data- 
    dir=C:\\Users\\Galdo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
    options.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 1");
    ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

And then you can make another method or if you use windows form application maybe you can use a button event for using tasks.
In your example you could use a button event like this:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod()); // you could add some arguments in your method
   var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod()); // maybe with different args
   ...
   ... // as many tasks you want, in your case 5
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i think that the problem is messing with few Chrome drivers, know anything about this ? BTW, I Need to loop this 200K times. So copying and pasteing won't work for me :(